# Creating Trigger during INSERT in MYSQL showing Error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-trigger

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Birth_Date date,
    Review_Date date,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

While inserting data into this table, I want to add a trigger that will update  column `Review_Date` with the value 1 year from birth date. Below is the trigger I have written and it's showing an error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tri_Test_Insert_Trigger 
AFTER INSERT 
ON persons
FOR Each row
BEGIN
    UPDATE persons
    SET review_date = dateadd(year,1,birth_date)
END
GO
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'END  GO' at line 8    0.000 sec

Comment: Edit your question and add the full text of the error message

Comment: You're missing a `;` on the end of your `UPDATE` query and after the `END`

Comment: It seemes you're using MSSQL instead, aren't you..?

Comment: try in this code in between begin and end:

UPDATE Persons
    SET Review_Date = DATEADD(year,1,Birth_Date);

Comment: there is no `GO` in mysql

Answer (score 3):

Three things need to be updated in your trigger:

a. need to add `;` at the end of your `UPDATE` sql
b. remove `GO` at the end of your trigger and use `DELIMITER` instead
c. `dateadd` needs to be changed to `date_add`

```
 DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER tri_Test_Insert_Trigger 
    AFTER INSERT 
    ON persons
    FOR Each row
    BEGIN
        UPDATE persons
        SET review_date = date_add(year,1,birth_date); -- add ; here
    END$$
  DELIMITER ; -- remove GO and use DELIMITER instead
```

Comment: I used this code and trigger is created. But when i insert the data to the table i am getting the error "dateadd does not exist" so i tried with date_add.Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1, birth_date); 
     END' at line 7 0.000 sec

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, no need to use a `begin..end` block or `DELIMITER` settings for only one statement.

By the way, you seemed to be confused between `MSSQL` ( where you can use `dateadd()` function and `GO` for ending blocks) and `MySQL`, in which use `date_add()` with different order and style of arguments as `(birth_date, interval 1 year)`, using as `date_add(year,1,birth_date)` produces `ERROR-1064`.

Preventing from getting `ERROR-1442`, use `BEFORE INSERT` trigger as the below format prefixed with `new.` :

```
mysql> DROP TRIGGER tri_Test_Insert_Trigger;

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER tri_Test_Insert_Trigger
    -> AFTER INSERT
    -> ON persons
    -> FOR Each row
    ->     UPDATE persons
    ->     SET review_date = date_add(birth_date, interval 1 year);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

mysql> insert into persons(lastname,birth_date) values('Özhan',date'2018-05-15');
ERROR 1442 (HY000): Cant update table 'persons' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
mysql> DROP TRIGGER tri_Test_Insert_Trigger;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER tri_Test_Insert_Trigger
    -> BEFORE INSERT
    -> ON persons
    -> FOR Each row
    ->     SET new.review_date = date_add(new.birth_date, interval 1 year);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> insert into persons(lastname,birth_date) values('Özhan',date'2018-05-15');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> select * from persons;
+----+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+
| ID | LastName | FirstName | Birth_Date | Review_Date |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+
|  2 | Özhan    | NULL      | 2018-05-15 | 2019-05-15  |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```